# Fabric, fabfile, fab: paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session

Tags: python, fabric

cf_key is my private ssh key. Please take a look at my traceback and my code to see what I'm doing wrong. I have redacted the actual server name and replaced it with "". Looks like "key cannot be used for signing." what is wrong with my key?

I executed the following command: `fab doit 'cf_key' refresh 'dev'` and got this error:

```
maintenance on
Exception: key cannot be used for signing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2109, in run
    handler(self.auth_handler, m)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 298, in _parse_service_accept
    sig = self.private_key.sign_ssh_data(blob)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/agent.py", line 418, in sign_ssh_data
    raise SSHException("key cannot be used for signing")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: key cannot be used for signing

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/bin/fab", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(program.run())
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 384, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 566, in execute
    executor.execute(*self.tasks)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/executor.py", line 129, in execute
    result = call.task(*args, **call.kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/tasks.py", line 127, in __call__
    result = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/fabfile.py", line 51, in refresh
    conn.run('sudo ln -sf /home/django/sites/{0}.campaignfinances.org/src/project/templates/maintenance.html {0}-maintenance.html'.format(server))
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in run
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 29, in opens
    self.open()
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/connection.py", line 634, in open
    self.client.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 764, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 740, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
  File "/home/michael/projects/campaignfinances/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1570, in auth_publickey
    raise SSHException("No existing session")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session
```

fabfile.py

```
###################################################################
#
# Usage:
# fab doit(path_to_ssh_key) refresh('dev|staging')
# fab doit(path_to_ssh_key) maintenanceon('dev|staging')
# fab doit(path_to_ssh_key) maintenanceoff('dev|staging')
#
# fab doit(path_to_ssh_key) productionrefresh
#
# Example: fab doit('c:\users\tom\.ssh\id_rsa.pem') maintenanceon('dev')
#
# If you use a passphrase then add --prompt-for-passphrase
####################################################################
from fabric import task, Connection


@task
def doit(ctx, keypath):
    ctx.user = 'django'
    ctx.host = '<servername>'
    ctx.connect_kwargs.key_filename = ''.format(keypath)


@task
def maintenanceon(ctx, server):
    conn = Connection(ctx.host, ctx.user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs)
    # create ln to maintenance file
    print('maintenance on')
    with conn.cd('/usr/share/nginx/html/'):
        conn.run('sudo ln -sf /home/django/sites/{0}.<servername>/src/project/templates/maintenance.html {0}-maintenance.html'.format(server))


@task
def maintenanceoff(ctx, server):
    conn = Connection(ctx.host, ctx.user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs)
    # create ln to maintenance file
    print('maintenance off')
    with conn.cd('/usr/share/nginx/html/'):
        conn.run('sudo unlink {}-maintenance.html'.format(server))


@task
def refresh(ctx, server):
    env_command = '. /home/django/sites/{0}.<servername>.com/{0}/bin/activate'.format(server)

    conn = Connection(ctx.host, ctx.user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs)

    # set to maintenance mode
    with conn.cd('/usr/share/nginx/html/'):
        print('maintenance on')
        conn.run('sudo ln -sf /home/django/sites/{0}.<servername>.com/src/project/templates/maintenance.html {0}-maintenance.html'.format(server))
    # refresh install
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/{}.<servername>.com/src/'.format(server)):
        print('git pull')
        conn.run('git pull')
    # check requirements
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/{}.<servername>.com/src/requirements/'.format(server)):
        print('pip-sync')
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'pip-sync {}.txt'.format(server))
    # run migrations and collectstatic
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/{}.<servername>.com/src/project/'.format(server)):
        print('migrate')
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'python manage.py migrate')
        print('collecstatic')
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'python manage.py collectstatic --no-input')
    # restart server
    print('restart server')
    conn.sudo('systemctl restart {}.service'.format(server), pty=True)

    # maintenance mode off
    with conn.cd('/usr/share/nginx/html/'):
        print('maintenance off)')
        conn.run('sudo unlink {}-maintenance.html'.format(server))


@task
def productionrefresh(ctx):
    env_command = '. /home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/www/bin/activate'

    conn = Connection(ctx.host, ctx.user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs)

    # set to maintenance mode
    with conn.cd('/usr/share/nginx/html/'):
        print('Set to maintenance mode')
        conn.run('sudo ln -sf /home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/src/project/templates/maintenance.html prod-maintenance.html')
    # refresh install
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/src/'):
        print('Git pull')
        conn.run('git pull')
    # check requirements
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/src/requirements/'):
        print('pip-sync production.txt')
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'pip-sync production.txt')
    # run migrations and collectstatic
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/src/project/'):
        print('python manage.py migrate')
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'python manage.py migrate')
        print('python manage.py collectstatic')
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'python manage.py collectstatic --no-input')
    # restart server
    print('restart production service')
    conn.sudo('systemctl restart production.service', pty=True)
    # maintenance mode off
    with conn.cd('/usr/share/nginx/html/'):
        print('maintenance off')
        conn.run('sudo unlink prod-maintenance.html')


@task
def productioncollect(ctx):
    env_command = '. /home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/www/bin/activate'

    conn = Connection(ctx.host, ctx.user, connect_kwargs=ctx.connect_kwargs)
    with conn.cd('/home/django/sites/www.<servername>.com/src/project/'):
        conn.run(env_command + '&&' + 'python manage.py collectstatic --no-input')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ssh to the server using the openssh client with that key?  The output indicates that your key can't be used for signing, which I've never seen before.

Also, test that the key is valid for signing like this:

```
redkrieg@cortex-0:~$ echo "signme" > testfile
redkrieg@cortex-0:~$ ssh-keygen -Y sign -f cf_key -n testsigning testfile
Signing file testfile
Write signature to testfile.sig
```

Make sure testfile.sig has an SSH SIGNATURE block in it after this.

Comment: Unknown option -Y